# Array copies zeros?

Tags: c, arrays

I have two arrays and if a number is repeated in 1 array I set that corresponding location in both to a value of zero. I then want to store it in a separate array now ignoring those zeros and copying the rest. However right now if I try this it just copies the array with the zeros, any idea?

```
  for (i = 0; i < linect; i++) //searches array sets repeated points to zero
  {
        if (array1[i] == array1[i+1])
        {
            array1[i] = array1[i + 1] = 0;
            array2[i] = array2[i + 1] = 0;
        }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < linect; i++)
  {
      if (array1[i] > 0.5){
          fixarray1[i] = array1[i];
          fixarray2[i] = array2[i];
      }
  }
j = 0;
while (j <300){
printf("\n%f", fixarray2[j]);
j++;
}
```

Comment: _"it just copies the array with the zeros"_ Could you explain a bit clearer exactly what that means? (e.g. by showing some sample input and output, and your expected output)

Comment: "I have two arrays..."  I see *four* arrrays in your code. Also, what if your `array2` was all zeros from the very beginning? Then your code will always print all zeros regardless of what  you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the loop below value is stored in fixarray only when element in array1 is not zero but its index gets incrementated even when element is zero.

```
for (i = 0; i < linect; i++)

{
      if (array1[i] > 0.5)
   {
      fixarray1[i] = array1[i];
      fixarray2[i] = array2[i];
   }
}
```

In this loop index of fixarray should incrementated only when value in array1 is not zero .Something like this -

```
int j=0;

for(i = 0; i < linect; i++)
 {
     if(array1[i]>0.5)
     {      
              fixarray1[j] = array1[i];
              fixarray2[j] = array2[i];
              j++;
     }
 }
```

This is will store value in fixarray only when element in array1 is not zero.

Comment: lol so it was working but the whole array was previously set to zero. I would increase "i" each time and it would copy what i needed over leaving the rest of the array as zeros, effectively just copying the array XD wow thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

So when you say "if a number is repeated in 1 array" do you mean if the number in the next index is the same as the current index or if the number is repeated in the entire array? As your code is, you are only checking the next value for repetition.

```
  for (i = 0; i < linect; i++)
  {
      if (array1[i] > 0.5){
          fixarray1[i] = array1[i];
          fixarray2[i] = array2[i];
      }
  }
```

Will only copy non-zero values into array 2 at the indices where there were non-zero values in array 1. So you're not actually removing any of the 0 values, you're just making another array `fixarray2[i]` that is the same as `array2[i]` .  You need to keep a separate counter if you want to skip all the zero's from your old array.